# Fatal error after instantiating block in Magento

Tags: template, blocks, ajax

I am trying to load in a block using ajax in Magento. To accomplish this the controller needs to create a block and pass through an array of data to the block's template. This part is quite simple and I have it working.

However, the template that gets called is also trying to call a block and `setData`:

```
$this->getChild('customerfriends.event.edit')->setData(
    'event', $event);
echo $this->getChild('customerfriends.event.edit')->toHtml();
```

`$this` does not seem to be an object which is causing a fatal error.

Is there something that I need to put in my class?

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Block_Event_Listsection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768543/fatal-error-after-instantiating-block-in-magento/18770585#18770585

Answer (score 2):

You can `setChild()` a child block.

Something like this:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'customerfriends.event.edit');
$this->setChild('customerfriends.event.edit', $block);
```

then the `toHtml()` evaluates to `''`;

I would put this into the `_beforeToHtml()` method of the block.

Comment: Where would I do this? In the controller or in the phtml ?

Comment: I would put this into the `_beforeToHtml()` method of the block.

Answer (score 2):

> $this does not seem to be an object which is causing a fatal error.

Lacking more context (i.e. how you're calling this template), the above seems incredibly unlikely.  **All** magento blocks are objects — the rendering looks a little like this

1. Block object is instantiated
2. Block has it's `toHtml` method called
3. A rendering method in the block `includes` in the `phtml` template

Because the `phtml` template is rendered from within a non-static class method, `$this` will **always** be an object.